# How to show the image in the UICollectionViewCell to another UIImageView? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Here's how my view controller looks like:

[image: Collection View Controller]

The UICollectionViewCell has its own custom class with an @IBOutlet for the image view. However, whenever I try to use the `didSelectItemAt` function on the CollectionViewController, the image view outlet is not being recognized. What I'm trying to do is when the user presses on the image from the collection view, it will show on the bigImageView (outside of the collection view).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    bigImageView.image = cell.smallImageView.image

}
```

The error says:

> *"Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'smallImageView' "*

What am I missing? Kindly enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using a custom cell here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your cell to the right subclass to access the `smallImageView` property:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourSubclass else {
        return
    }

    bigImageView.image = cell.smallImageView.image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, did you set the UICollectionViewCell to your "custom class," or will the storyboard generate just a UICollectionViewCell object, which does not have your smallImageView?

Answer (score 0):

try it on objective-c  not working

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ImgCollectionCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Mainimg.image = cell.img.image;
}
```

I get white background image